# How to deduce "statistical significance" given error and fit deviation

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, standard-error, error

I have a best-estimate value for some quantity $H$, along with uncertainty $\delta H$. I am told that the best-estimate $H$ was determined by fitting some unknown function involving $H$ and an arbitrary number $n$ of other parameters, $g(H; x_0...x_n)$, to a set of data. $H$ is thus the resultant best-fit parameter with uncertainty $\delta H$. I am also given the reduced sum of square deviations of the data to the fitting function the determined $H$, $\chi^2$.

This is all I know. I do not have the raw data that was fit to, nor how many points were used in the fit. All I have is

$$H$$
$$\delta H$$
$$\chi^2$$

Using these three pieces of information, is it possible to deduce the statistical significance of the best-estimate value $H$?

Comment: What exactly does the "uncertainty" $\delta H$ represent?  If it can be related to the sampling variance of $H$, and if you can justify specific assumptions about the sampling distribution of $H$, then you can do something.  But if either one of these doesn't hold, all bets are off.

Comment: @whuber I've got no idea. I assume it is the standard error in the parameter fit. I

Comment: That could be a risky assumption, since people report radically different values of "uncertainty": in addition to an SE, it could be two or three SEs, a 50%/90%/95%/99% (or whatever) credible/confidence (half-)interval, or even sometimes the SD of the data from which $H$ was estimated. The first thing, then, is to find out what $\delta H$ actually means.

Comment: @whuber I was able to gather enough information to determine that the data in question is indeed fit with a standard Gaussian form, at least. I'll email the author of this paper as to more details of the error estimate. Even if I *do* find out this information, is it possible to recover a statistical significance?